# c# flickering Listview on update

Tags: c#, listview, flicker

I have a list view that is periodically updated (every 60 seconds). It was anoying to me that i would get a flicker every time it up dated. The method being used was to clear all the items and then recreate them. I decided to instead of clearing the items I would just write directly to the cell with the new text. Is this a better approach or does anyone have a better solution.

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.8) recommends wrapping bulks of updates in BeginUpdate/EndUpdate. I tested and it helps (the link is on the ListBox, but the same seems to apply for ListView - as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196130/1219280))

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The ListView control has a flicker issue. The problem appears to be that the control's Update overload is improperly implemented such that it acts like a Refresh. An Update should cause the control to redraw only its invalid regions whereas a Refresh redraws the control’s entire client area. So if you were to change, say, the background color of one item in the list then only that particular item should need to be repainted. Unfortunately, the ListView control seems to be of a different opinion and wants to repaint its entire surface whenever you mess with a single item… even if the item is not currently being displayed. So, anyways, you can easily suppress the flicker by rolling your own as follows:

```
class ListViewNF : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
{
    public ListViewNF()
    {
        //Activate double buffering
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
        // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
    }

    protected override void OnNotifyMessage(Message m)
    {
        //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
        if(m.Msg != 0x14)
        {
            base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
        }
    }
}
```

From: [Geekswithblogs.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118172015/http://geekswithblogs.net/CPound/archive/2006/02/27/70834.aspx)

Comment: You have to know that the downside of this solution (due to the double buffering) is that updating the control is significantly slower (try adding a 1000 items).

Comment: To be honest, I never use the winforms listview. But isn't that perfomance loss away when you call **SuspendLayout** and **ResumeLayout**?

Comment: Thank you Stormenent. I have been looking for an solution to this issue for a while and this works well for me.

Comment: The OptimizedDoubleBuffer does it work properly. But I don't think skipping the call to base.OnNotifyMessage(m) helps in any way. I just checked with ILSpy and Control.OnNotifyMessage has an empty implementation. From MSDN: "When overriding OnNotifyMessage in a derived class, calling the base class's OnNotifyMessage method is not necessary because there is no initial implementation." This method is there so subclasses can be notified when messages are processed. If you need to alter those messages, you need to override WndProc ?

Comment: If you don't like this solution, because of subclassing, here is very similar without subclassing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87795/how-to-prevent-flickering-in-listview-when-updating-a-single-listviewitems-text

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the other replies, many controls have a `[Begin|End]Update()` method that you can use to reduce flickering when editing the contents - for example:

```
    listView.BeginUpdate();
    try {
        // listView.Items... (lots of editing)
    } finally {
        listView.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: Huge thanks! I've been searching the Internet up and down, and none of the search results are applicable :D

Comment: I found that this helps but does not fully remove flickering.

Answer (score 25):

Here is my quick fix for a C# implementation that does not require subclassing the list views etc.

Uses reflection to set the DoubleBuffered Property to true in the forms constructor.

```
    lvMessages
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .SetValue(lvMessages, true, null);
```

Update for 2021:
I got pinged on this old post with a comment and I would write this code differently now. Below is an extension method that will add a new method to a ListView to be able to set the double buffered property to true/false as required. This will then extend all list views and make it easier to call as reqired.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for List Views
/// </summary>
public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the double buffered property of a list view to the specified value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listView">The List view</param>
    /// <param name="doubleBuffered">Double Buffered or not</param>
    public static void SetDoubleBuffered(this System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView, bool doubleBuffered = true)
    {
        listView
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(listView, doubleBuffered, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is by far the simplest solution to implement.  Requires no sub classing and allows use of an unmodifed list view from the visual studio tool box.  Shame DoubleBuffered is not just exposed as public!

Comment: By far the best solution. Tks

Comment: @RegisSt-Gelais Thanks, I have just added an alternate extension method version instead that would make it easier to extend all list views with the same functionality. I wrote the original code a few years ago and I would do it with extension methods these days.

Comment: @WraithNath It looks a lot to what I coded in my projet :)

Comment: This should have been the default ListView behavior (DoubleBuffered set to True), its so plain dumb!

Answer (score 7):

If this can help, the following component solved my ListView flickering issues with .NET 3.5

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ListView))]
public class ListViewDoubleBuffered : ListView
{
    public ListViewDoubleBuffered()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

I use it in conjonction with .BeginUpdate() and .EndUpdate() methods where I do ListView.Items manipulation.

I don't understand why this property is a protected one...even in the .NET 4.5 (maybe a security issue)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, make it double buffered. It will reduce the flicker ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.doublebuffered.aspx

Comment: -1: You can't set a `ListView`s DoubleBuffered property (it's protected).

Comment: -1 to your comment because you CAN set it, if you derive a new class from it, there is also the "SetStyle" method. But way to do your research before down voting somebody, even when you answered using the exact reason your comment makes no sense *thumbs up*

Comment: just remember, SetStyle is protected too... how did you managed to call that?

Answer (score 5):

Excellent question and Stormenent's answer was spot on. Here's a C++ port of his code for anyone else who might be tackling C++/CLI implementations.

```
#pragma once

#include "Windows.h" // For WM_ERASEBKGND

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class FlickerFreeListView : public ListView
{
public:
    FlickerFreeListView()
    {
        //Activate double buffering
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles::AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
        // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
        SetStyle(ControlStyles::EnableNotifyMessage, true);
    }

protected:
    virtual  void OnNotifyMessage(Message m) override
    {
        //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
        if(m.Msg != WM_ERASEBKGND)
        {
            ListView::OnNotifyMessage(m);
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following extension class to set the `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`:

```
using System.Reflection;

public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    public static void SetDoubleBuffered(this ListView listView, bool value)
    {
        listView.GetType()
            .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(listView, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest Solution would probably be using

```
       listView.Items.AddRange(listViewItems.ToArray());
```

instead of

```
       foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in listViewItems)
       {
           listView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
       }
```

This works way better.

Comment: Thank you so much had real trouble with blocking my complete GUI with just adding items this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**

```
yourlistview.BeginUpdate()

//Do your update of adding and removing item from the list

yourlistview.EndUpdate()
```

Comment: This worked for me when I had a listview that I had limited to 100 items, and I was deleting the first row when adding a new row if that threshold was met.

Comment: Not a useful answer to the question raised because (since edit version 3 way back in 2008) the OP said he was already doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an *extremely* old question and answer.  However, this is the top result when searching for "C++/cli listview flicker" - despite the fact that this isn't even talking about C++.  So here's the C++ version of this:

I put this in the header file for my main form, you can choose to put it elsewhere...

```
static void DoubleBuffer(Control^ control, bool enable) {
    System::Reflection::PropertyInfo^ info = control->GetType()->
        GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System::Reflection::BindingFlags::Instance 
            | System::Reflection::BindingFlags::NonPublic);
    info->SetValue(control, enable, nullptr);
}
```

If you happen to land here looking for a similar answer for managed C++, that works for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked best for me.
Since you are editing the cell directly, the best solution in your case would be to simply refresh/reload that particular cell/row instead of the entire table.
You could use the `RedrawItems(...)` method that basically repaints only the specified range of items/rows of the listview.

```
public void RedrawItems(int startIndex, int endIndex, bool invalidateOnly);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.redrawitems?view=netframework-4.8)
This totally got rid of the *full listview flicker* for me.
Only the relevant item/record flickers while getting updated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If someone would still look an answer for this, I used a timer for a slight delay and it solved the problem nicely. I wanted to highlight (change colour) for the entire row on mouse move event, but I think it would work for item replacement etc. For me listView.BeginUpdate() and listView.EndUpdate() didn't work, DoubleBuffered property also didn't work, I have googled a lot and nothing worked.

```
private int currentViewItemIndex;
private int lastViewItemIndex;

    private void listView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        ListViewItem lvi = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if (lvi != null && lastViewItemIndex == -1)
        {
            listView.Items[lvi.Index].BackColor = Color.Green;
            lastViewItemIndex = lvi.Index;
        }

        if (lvi != null && lastViewItemIndex != -1)
        {
            currentViewItemIndex = lvi.Index;
            listViewTimer.Start(); 
        } 
    }

    private void listViewTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView.BeginUpdate();
        listView.Items[lastViewItemIndex].BackColor = Colour.Transparent;
        listView.Items[currentViewItemIndex].BackColor = Colour.Green;
        listView.EndUpdate();
        lastViewItemIndex = currentViewItemIndex;
        listViewTimer.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the double buffered property in true.

Also you could use:

```
this.SuspendLayout();

//update control

this.ResumeLayout(False);

this.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: Layout mainly applies when moving/resizing things... I suspect you mean [Begin|End]Update, as per my reply.

Answer (score 0):

In Winrt Windows phone 8.1 you can set the following code to fix this issue.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection/>      
</ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, in my case, I simply had to add a call to

> Application.EnableVisualStyles()

before running the application, like this:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Otherwise, double buffering is not enough. Maybe it was a very old project and new ones have that setting by default...