# Preventing ListBox scrolling to top when updated

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to build a simple music player with a ListBox playlist. When adding audio files to the playlist, it first fills the ListBox with the filenames and then (on a separate thread) extracts the ID3 data and overwrites the filenames with the correct Artist - Title information (much like Winamp).

But while the ListBox is being updated, it's unscrollable, as it always jumps to the top on every item overwrite.

Any way to prevent this?

**EDIT:**
The code:

```
public Form1()
{
    //Some initialization code omitted here

    BindingList<TAG_INFO> trackList = new BindingList<TAG_INFO>();

    // The Playlist
    this.playlist = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
    this.playlist.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    this.playlist.Name = "playlist";
    this.playlist.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 316);
    this.playlist.DataSource = trackList;
}

private void playlist_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Initialize OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog opd = new OpenFileDialog();
    opd.Filter = "Music (*.WAV; *.MP3; *.FLAC)|*.WAV;*.MP3;*.FLAC|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    opd.Title = "Select Music";
    opd.Multiselect = true;

    //Open OpenFileDialog
    if (DialogResult.OK == opd.ShowDialog())
    {

        //Add opened files to playlist
        for (int i = 0; opd.FileNames.Length > i; ++i)
        {
            if (File.Exists(opd.FileNames[i]))
            {
                trackList.Add(new TAG_INFO(opd.FileNames[i]));
            }
        }

        //Initialize BackgroundWorker
        BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(thread_trackparser_DoWork);
        _bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_bw_ProgressChanged);

        //Start ID3 extraction
        _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}

void thread_trackparser_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker _bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 0; i < trackList.Count; ++i)
    {
        //Pass extracted tag info to _bw_ProgressChanged for thread-safe playlist entry update
        _bw.ReportProgress(0,new object[2] {i, BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromFile(trackList[i].filename)});
    }
}

void _bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object[] unboxed = e.UserState as object[];

    trackList[(int)unboxed[0]] = (unboxed[1] as TAG_INFO);
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Much simpler test case:
Try scrolling down without selecting an item. The changing ListBox will scroll to the top again.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();

            // listBox1
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 290);

            // timer1
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);

            // Form1
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 290);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
                listBox1.Items.Add(i);
        }

        int tickCounter = -1;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (++tickCounter > 44) tickCounter = 0;
            listBox1.Items[tickCounter] = ((int)listBox1.Items[tickCounter])+1;
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code please. The way it is being updated could be related to the issue.

Comment: Much simpler code for demonstrating the same problem added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice repro code, I had no trouble diagnosing the source of the problem.  It is a feature, not a bug.  Press the arrow down key several times, then scroll the list.  Note that it doesn't jump back now.

What's going on here is that list box automatically scrolls the item with the focus back into view when it gets updated.  This is normally desirable behavior, you cannot turn it off.  Workarounds, like selecting the item you're updating, isn't going to be pretty when you update the list like this, it is going to flicker badly.  Maybe virtual mode, I didn't try it.

ListView doesn't have this behavior, consider using it instead.  Use View = List or Details.

Comment: Nice exhaustive answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly! Also used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442817 to get rid of the flickering during update.

Answer (score 1):

It might be prudent to disable any painting of the Listbox when doing the updates. Use ListBox`.BeginUpdate()` and then update the entries, when done, invoke ListBox`.EndUpdate()`. This should ensure that no refreshes occurs during the update.

You should also ensure that you do not refresh the ListBox from a thread either as cross-threading is dis-allowed, and the runtime will barf with a message saying that 'Cross Threading Exception' has occurred.

Use the ListBox's `BeginInvoke(...)` method to get around the cross threading issue. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) on the MSDN on how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .BeginUpdate() is a good solution:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub
Dim ix As Integer
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    ix = ListBox1.TopIndex
    Label1.Text = ListBox1.TopIndex     'get most top displayed in the listbox
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()              'do not refresh during update
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()              'do updates
    For i = 1 To 100
        ListBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString & "." & Int((101) * Rnd()).ToString)
    Next
    ListBox1.TopIndex = ix              'set the top item to be displayed
    ListBox1.EndUpdate()                'refresh the listbox

End Sub

Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) _
Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
    VScrollBar1.Maximum = ListBox1.Items.Count
    ListBox1.TopIndex = VScrollBar1.Value       ' link another scrollbar if you want
    Label2.Text = VScrollBar1.Value

End Sub
```

End Class

The code speaks by himself. A timer is generating random number. The numbers are populated in the List Box. Before the update just read the current Top Index of the List Box. During the update switch off the rendering by Begin Update. Then restore the Top Index and call End Update.

I put an extra Scroll Bar, linked to the List Box.

Comment: Thanks. `TopIndex` solved for me. And Begin/EndUpdate keeps the refresh more "smooth".