# How to change ListBox to ListView in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

I have a `ListBox` control in my WinForms application that scrolls to the first element every time when I update it via the following code:

```
listBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(someDicrionary, null);
```

According to the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889172/preventing-listbox-scrolling-to-top-when-updated) question, it's a feature, not a bug, and we should use `ListView` control instead of `ListBox` to avoid such behavior.

Unfortunately, I have a lot of code that relies on a `ListBox` interface and changing `ListBox` to the `ListView` control results in a lot of errors. For example, I don't have such properties like `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` in `ListView`, so I don't know how to bind it properly.

There is also no `IndexFromPoint` method in `ListView` which I need to get an item under cursor and I need properties like `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` for later usage (for example, in the right-clicking event).

What is the best way to change `ListBox` to `ListView` in my case?

Is there any other workaround to get rid off this flickering btw?

Comment: ListView is a horrible control IMHO. OK if you have a need for the special display modes w/images, but if you are using a plain list the ListBox would be superior IMO.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do such change, the best way is creating a `UserControl` that hosts a `ListView` and implement such properties and methods for your `UserControl`.

For example:

```
//Just for sample, you should add some checks and raise some events and throw some exceptions.
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get
    {
        var selectedIndex = -1;
        if (this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            selectedIndex = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
        return selectedIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        this.listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
            .ToList().ForEach(item =>
            {
                item.Selected = false;
            });
        this.listView1.Items[value].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Implementing user control is for being independent from `ListView` and not to expose `ListView` members. But if it is not a concern for you, you can inherit from `ListView` and add properties and methods that you want to it, for example:

```
public int IndexFromPoint(Point p)
{
    return this.IndexFromPoint(p.X, p.Y);
}
public int IndexFromPoint(int x, int y)
{
    var item = this.HitTest(x, y).Item;
    if (item != null)
        return item.Index;

    return -1;
}

private string displayMember;
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public string DisplayMember
{
    get
    {
        return displayMember;
    }
    set
    {
        displayMember = value;
    }
}

private string valueMember;
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public string ValueMember
{
    get
    {
        return valueMember;
    }
    set
    {
        valueMember = value;
    }
}
```

### Edit

---

As another alternative that sounds good; you can create a [`WPF UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) that hosts a [`WPF ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) that seems doesn't suffer from that scroll problem. This way you can host your usercontrol in windows forms using an [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) control.
As I tested when you add new items to it, the scroll remains where it is now.

Comment: To be honest, I don't want it but I don't see any other option to avoid this flickering behavior in `ListBox` control

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `ListBox` from WPF doesn't have a lot of other stuff -- for example, `IndexFromPoint` method. And I need to have a separate DLL project in my solution then for this control only

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some ideas you may find useful - in VB but easily translated to C#

Flicker addressed by the begin/end. Selecting the proper row would need some attention obviously.

```
    lb1.BeginUpdate()
    lb1.Sorted = True
    Dim dv As DataTable = Gen.GetDataTable("Select Facility_Name from Facility")
    lb1.DisplayMember = "Facility_name"
    lb1.ValueMember = "Facility_name"
    lb1.DataSource = dv
    lb1.SelectedIndex = 40
    lb1.EndUpdate()
```

Comment: So what's the trick about it? Why should I place the "binding" code between `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` calls and what is this 40 in `SelectedIndex` means?

Comment: With my test the begin/end removed the flicker. SelectedInex was just there to show how to move the list to a given point - 40 was just a test

Comment: I didn't understand the part with `SelectedIndex` anyway. I don't need to move the list to a given point, I need a control that doesn't flicker when I change its `DataSource`

Comment: Sorry - I was out in the weeds answering using the ListBox instead of ListView.