# How to update ListBox control with Dictionary binded to it without jumping to the first item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is there any way to update a `ListBox` control with `Dictionary` binded to it without resetting its `DataSource` property on every dictionary change? The reason I don't like this solution is that it forces a `ListBox` control to jump to the first item as mentioned in other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889172/preventing-listbox-scrolling-to-top-when-updated).

Here is a minimal example that reproduces this behavior -- https://bitbucket.org/ntrophimov/updating_issue (about 20 lines of code to read in the `MainForm.cs` file)

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Is there any dictionary implementation in which I can manipulate items (add and remove them) and these changes will be immediately represented in a `ListBox` control without refreshing its whole content?

Comment: So you want to build something like `Observable` `Dictionary` ?

Comment: @Jasper Maybe, I just want to fix this updating behavior

Comment: Hmmm.. If you worried for visual selection you could save it as `Selected={Binding SelectedItem}` and just restore it back after you update the `ItemsSource` setter/getter

Comment: @Jasper I'm using WinForms, not WPF (look at the tags)

Comment: But does my solution looks good (if we rephrase it for WinForms) ? or you looking for something else ?

Comment: @Jasper I didn't understand you at all. Could you rephrase it pls?

Comment: The idea is: 1. You show your `ListBox` with items 2. User click on some item 3. Applications save the 'selected' item in local variable 4. User/App initiate `ListBox` update process 5. Update process done -> application restore (re-assign) the 'selected' item (if it still valid for current items of `ListBox`)

Comment: @Jasper Then a user will see a flickering because of reassigning the selected item I think

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I guess in WinForms there was something like `control.StartEditing()` and `control.EndEditiing()` or something like this... Some functions that could temporary suspend GUI thread from refreshing your control until you release it

Comment: @Jasper Ok, but what if a user didn't select any item? He just scrolled a `ListBox` control some time and then `DataSource` reassigning scrolled it back to the first item in the list

Comment: Hmm... This is default behaviour of list controls. There's not build-in restore-position mechanism in Windows controls. You could mimic this by hooking on 'selected' item but without hooking.... I'm not sure that WinForms `ListBox` has a scrool position property - and if so you must be 100% sure that this is almost the same items because it will look strange to scrool to the same position for different items in `ListBox`... Are you sure that you have those requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

1. You show your `ListBox` with items
2. User click on some item
3. Applications save the 'selected' item in local variable
4. User/App initiate `ListBox` update process
5. Update process done -> application restore (re-assign) the 'selected' item (if it still valid for current items of `ListBox`)