# Is there any way to avoid listView flickering when updating the items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void downloader_Succeeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileDownloader.FileInfo fi = downloader.CurrentFile;
            string name = fi.Path;
            foreach (ListViewItem lvw in listView1.Items)
            {
                if (lvw.Text == name)
                    lvw.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            label6.Text = countFilesDownloaded++.ToString();
        }
```

Each time when it's coloring the item it's flickering.
I saw some answers but none of them is working.

I saw this answer:

[Flickering answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms)

And this one

[Flickering answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)

Maybe i didn't use them right. But they didn't work.

Tried to add this to the form1 at the bottom:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
  get {
    var parms = base.CreateParams;
    parms.Style &= ~0x02000000;  // Turn off WS_CLIPCHILDREN
    return parms;
  }
}
```

Then tried to create instance of this each time a item was coloring inside the event.

Comment: The method desribed in the end is called automatically by Win forms (Windows) via recursion, You dont have to call that. As you just change color of 1 item, what is flickering? Whole listbox or the item? I would consider calling 'SuspendLayout()' on listbox at the start and its resume + 'Refresh()' at the end of download method

Comment: Wouldn't this problem be situational where the majority of downloads are completed rather quickly?  Is this a realistic situation?

Answer (score 4):

I had your problem and after doing some research it appears that the ListView control repaints its entire area whenever you modify a single item. The solution is to subclass the ListView and filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message.  This did the trick for me.

For more information see here:
[c# flickering Listview on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442817/c-sharp-flickering-listview-on-update)

```
public partial class ListViewNF : ListView
{
    public ListViewNF()
    {
    }

    public ListViewNF(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);

        InitializeComponent();

        //Activate double buffering
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |  
        ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
        // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
    }

    protected override void OnNotifyMessage(Message m)
    {
        //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
        if (m.Msg != 0x14)
        {
            base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you resize the window?  Sometimes controls end up painting over themselves

Comment: @MickyD - No repainting or flicking occurs on resize.  My ListView class uses multple colors to color lines as well as colors for the background of certain list items.