# Owner Draw Large Icon Listview--Prevent Constant Redrawing when Scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, graphics

I'm using the ListView Control, with `View = LargeIcon`, to present thumbnails of images coming from a database.
The problem is that when an icon is selected, the default rendering always puts a terrible looking blue cast over the image.

Here's an example, showing the unselected and selected views.

[image: Unselected View]

Here's the selected view.

[image: Selected View]

I then created a more pleasing thumbnail using Owner Draw placing a blue rectangle around the text showing that the thumbnail had been selected, but leaving the image unchanged.  Here's the result.

[image: Owner Draw Image]

The only problem is that whenever multiple thumbnails are selected, they are constantly being redrawn when scrolling making the control pretty much unusable, unlike use of the default drawing. It looks terrible, but there is no redrawing when scrolled.

Here's my code.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
private void listView6_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
        {
            //get image
            Image img = thumbList256.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex];
           
            //draw image                    
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(e.Bounds.X + ((e.Bounds.Width - img.Width) / 2), e.Bounds.Y + 3));

            //fill rectangle arount text
            Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + img.Height + 3, e.Bounds.Width, 40);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highlightBrush, textRect);

            //draw text
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, smallFont, highlightTextBrush, new RectangleF(new PointF(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + img.Height + 3), new SizeF(e.Bounds.Width, 40)), new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center });
        }                
    }
    else
    {                
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }                        
}
```

Comment: Enable [double-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442817/c-sharp-flickering-listview-on-update) and prep the images so they paint fast.  Which requires resizing them to tile size and using the 32bppPArgb bitmap format.

Comment: ...Then remove that `using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)` (why did you put that in?), also you're calculating the same Rectangle twice. You should use `TextRendrer.DrawText()`  to draw the text-- Specify how many images you have in there and what is the ImageList set to -- It doesn't look like the ListView has a background image. If it has one instead, remove it

Comment: @HansPassant Already double buffered. Size of images are 256x192 using 32bppPArgb bitmap format. They've already been resized and are loaded from an Sqlite DB when the app starts.

Comment: @Jimi  Changed code as suggested.  No background image.  Still the same.  Will try to upload a screen recording to show exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Check if anything in your code is triggering excessive redraws/refreshes. I tried to recreate the behavior based on the code you provided, but it worked fine.

Comment: If the LV is already double-buffered, then show that piece of code, too. It's relevant to the question. Also add the other information: how many images are you loading? + Does something else happen when a selection is performed?

Comment: Not likely the issue, but it appears that `thumbList256` is an ImageList. If so, you should be disposing of the Image returned from its ImageCollection as it is a copy. See the Remarks section of [ImageList.ImageCollection.Item Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.item?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-windows-forms-imagelist-imagecollection-item(system-int32)).