# Prevent flickering in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I know this question already asked and i have found this answer: [How to prevent flickering in ListView when updating a single ListViewItem's text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87795/how-to-prevent-flickering-in-listview-when-updating-a-single-listviewitems-text)

I created this class from the first respond and when my form loaded i created an instance from this class but from here what i need to do to prevent the flickering ?

Comment: You just used the wrong answer.  Start from the bottom and pick the answer that uses 3 lines of code.  Which is all it takes.  An answer isn't better because it uses more code.  On the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly ran through that anwser and i suspect that calling the `EnableDoubleBuffer(myListVeiew);` should be what you're looking for...