# How to double buffer list view in c#. (step by step)

Tags: c#, listview, doublebuffered

I am using a listview (listView1) which is flickering when i populate data into it(adding 10 lines in every second).

How can I enable double buffer property to make it flicker free.

Please give me step by step instructions. I am new to c#.

Comment: posible dupliacte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87795/how-to-prevent-flickering-in-listview-when-updating-a-single-listviewitems-text

Comment: I tried this. But since i am populating very fast, it is freezing my application..

Comment: can you post sample code, so we can see what is going on?

Comment: My application is connected to an external hardware. The hardware will pump huge amount of messages(~100 lines/ second) to the application. I am writing this in to listView. I am using the same code to enable double buffering and calling  'ListViewHelper.EnableDoubleBuffer(listView1);' upon checking a checkBox. Without double buffering, the app work good but the listview flicker too much.

Answer (score 1):

At 100 lines per second, you are going to need double buffering and virtual mode.

Double buffering requires subclassing a ListView and setting the `DoubleBuffered` protected property. Virtual mode requires setting `VirtualSize` to the number of rows and then responding the `RetrieveVirtualItem` event.

You should seriously consider using [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) which is an open source wrapper around the .NET ListView that solves LOTS of problems so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

One option here, would be to only update the listview datasource, so that your not directly accessing your control, only the underlying datasource.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//load the Datatable with items from your external hardware connection.
myListView.datasource = dt;
```

Then you only update the DataTable, not the control's list of items.  With double buffering, you should see the affect you require.

Lastly, 100 listview items per second is a lot, do you need to have this many items in the listview?  I would suggest filtering this list to only items you need at the time, will make it perform much better.