# C#: Avoid flickering when painting?

Tags: c#, panel, paint, flicker, invalidation

I want to make a simple application that allows to draw a line. When you click with the mouse you set the initial coords of the line. Then, by moving the mouse, you lengthen or shorten the line. So, every time my panel (I'm using System.Windows.Forms) detect that my mouse's moving, it should draw a new line, as this will be different (even by one pixel) from the previous one. The main problem is, first, that I don't know exactly how to handle repainting in C# (I used to use Java, and for some aspects repainting was easier) and second, that when I call the **panel.Invalidate()** method, everything is flickering. I also tried to use the **panel.Invalidate(Region r)** method by using as parameter a rectangle, but it still flickers.

This is the class where my panel operates. The Road object contains the method that paints the line. In the **panel1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)** method I only color the background. In the **panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)** method I paint the line.

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Manager manager;

    Graphics g;

    Road road;
    Point initPosition;

    bool roadOn;
    bool mouseDown;

    public Form1(Manager manager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.manager = manager;

        g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        road = new Road(0, 0, 0, 0, new Pen(Color.Gray, 10));
        initPosition = new Point(0, 0);

        roadOn = false;
        mouseDown = false;
   }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = Cursor.Position;

        if(panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(position))
        {
            if(e.KeyChar.ToString() == Keys.R.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                roadOn = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;

        initPosition = Cursor.Position;
        road.X = initPosition.X;
        road.Y = initPosition.Y;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Invalidate();
        panel1.Dispose();
        panel1.Update();

        Point position = Cursor.Position;

        if(roadOn)
        {
            if(mouseDown)
            {
                road.X2 = position.X;
                road.Y2 = position.Y;

                road.paint(g);
            }
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

This is the **Road** class:

```
class Road : GameObject
{
    Pen pen;
    public Pen Pen
    {
        get { return pen; }
        set { pen = value; }
    }

    int x2;
    public int X2
    {
        get { return x2; }
        set { x2 = value; }
    }

    int y2;
    public int Y2
    {
        get { return y2; }
        set { y2 = value; }
    }

    public Road(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Pen pen) : base(x1, y1)
    {
        this.pen = pen;
    }

    override public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want some double buffering. Your clearing of the drawing area is being rendered, hence the flickering. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Look into double buffering

Comment: I haven't done this sort of thing for a while, but I suspect that you should just be recording the mouse coords and calling `Invalidate` in the mouse move event, then do all the drawing within the `Paint` event.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87795/how-to-prevent-flickering-in-listview-when-updating-a-single-listviewitems-text/15268338#15268338).

Comment: Also `CreateGraphics` is horrible, you should always do painting in a controls `Paint` event

Comment: If this is for a game I would recommend to stay away from Graphics as much as you can, you will not achieve a good performance at all. Use OpenGL or DirectX, there are wrappers for them like OpenTK and SharpDX and these API's are specifically targeted on intensive graphic tasks.

Comment: Either use a Panel subclass with Doublebuffering on : `class DrawPanel: Panel
    {
        public DrawPanel() { DoubleBuffered = true; }
    }`  or go for a PictureBox, which was meant for drawing and can also display two Image layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Panel` control has a `DoubleBuffered` property but it's protected. The best solution is then extend it to override the property to true and use the new class to draw:

Create a class inheriting from Panel:

```
//Make it sealed so you can call DoubleBuffered from the constructor safely.
public sealed class DoubleBufferedPanel : Panel
{
    public DoubleBufferedPanel()
    {
        //I want this class only for drawing so force the value to true here
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Replace your panel in the Form with an instance of the previously created class.

With only this minor change you should see zero-flicker drawing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I don't exactly how to edit the Form class and where to put the new methods. It's because I used visual studio automatic tool to create the panel and the methods.

Comment: Visual studio designer generates code as result of your actions. You can find the generated code in a Form1.Desginer.cs (assuming your form is called Form1). In solution explorer expand the files nested under your form class. Locate the panel1 (you can search for it) and change the type to DoubleBuffered class. Locate also the part where it's created in InitializeComponent method.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked. Anyway thanks to everyone that answered my question :).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue 2 weeks ago. The problem is that you have to set custom control styles to allow double buffer.

```
SetStyle( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true );
```

and You can override CreateParams property like so:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x20;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Another problem is that you use Invalidate() method which requests full validation of a control. Use Refresh() method instead and remove Invalidate() and Update() methods.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. I did that, but still it is flickering. Maybe it's because this issues depend on every single case.

Comment: For this you should override the panel class like:

Comment: class MePanel : Panel { public MePanel() : base() { InitializeComponent(); SetStyle( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true ); } ... CreateParams ... }